# Firebase Storage Denying Image Delete Request: Error Domain=FIRStorageErrorDomain Code=-13021 "User does not have permission to access"

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage, firebase-security

I have an iOS app where users can add annotations to a MapView (the annotations contain data like a title, images, Firebase uid, image fullpath etc.), and the data is uploaded to Firestore as a document, while the image associated with the annotation is uploaded to Firebase Storage.  I access the image using its fullPath, which is stored in the corresponding document in Firestore.  The problem I'm having is that my Firestore and Storage security rules only permit the creator of a document / image to delete it, and while Firestore is permitting the delete request, Storage is continuing to deny it, despite the same circumstances seemingly working in the test environment.  Here are my Storage security rules:

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /images/{userId}/{image} {
  
      allow read;
      allow create: if request.auth != null;
      allow delete: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userId;
  
    }
  }
}
```

Here is how the fullPath string of the image that I upload to Firestore is created (the constant 'fileURL' is simply the stored string of the local URL of the image in the user's phone):

```
let imagesFilesRef = storageRef.child("images/\(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid)/\(fileURL.absoluteString.replacingOccurrences(of: "/", with: "."))")
```

And here is how I call the deletion of the image (tappedAnnotation is the annotation I am deleting, and I am accessing the fullPath stored in Firestore, which exactly matches the file path of how it's stored in Storage):

```
// Create a reference to the file to delete
let imageRef = storageRef.child("\(tappedAnnotation.fullPath)")
                                                
// Delete the file
imageRef.delete { error in
  if let error = error {
    print(error)
  } else {
    print("Image successfully deleted!")
  }
}
```

When the creator of this annotation, with the correct uid, is signed in, my delete request is still being denied.  Here's an exact example of something I have tried: I created an annotation with an image associated with it, signed in with a Firebase uid (just a test user) of "6CiLpg9gmsOUNC4NJgoz7RHjBeU2".  Upon creation of the annotation, the fullPath was uploaded to Firestore with this exact value:

> "images/6CiLpg9gmsOUNC4NJgoz7RHjBeU2/file:...Users.Derek.Library.Developer.CoreSimulator.Devices.DA2742F3-DE68-4488-A5DF-20F10EEC8199.data.Containers.Data.Application.DDD1FC6A-EC8C-4070-A4F4-6F6645640B30.tmp.34C8EF1A-6130-4650-A684-7C0ED46690B5.jpeg"

Yet upon delete request, access was denied, although the {userId} section of my security rules exactly matches the uid of the user making the request.  Any idea why this is not working? Thanks for any help.

Comment: I've found the same error here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38467395/firebase-storage-error-firstorageerrordomain-code-13021-user-does-not-have-p). Would this help you?

Comment: That does appear to be a the same error, although his permission is being denied for a slightly different reason it seems.  Mine is due to the userId not matching up correctly (somehow :/ even though it looks good to me) I believe.  Also, that issue has not been solved either, so there isn't anything really helpful there, thanks for trying though.

Comment: Hello. You said that this program works in the test environment but not in production. Can you tell me more about it?

Comment: Yes, so the test environment I am referring to is the Firebase Playground Rules test.  If you are familiar with the format, you can specify things like the UID of the user making the request, specify the file path they are trying to access, etc.  So when I went to do a quick test, with the exact example mentioned above.  I specified the conditions of the test as, user is requesting a delete, user is authenticated, their UID is the one I mentioned above, and the file path they were trying to access in storage is the same as the one mentioned above.  The test PASSED in playground.

Comment: If your test passes in the test but failing in production, all the while the same code, I would suggest creating a bug to look into this for you. You may look here (https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/report/bugs) to report a bug to be investigated.